# How do I prevent a third party app from accessing my GMail?

Tags: gmail

I let a third party application have access to my GMail.  Now I want to remove this access.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 12):

If you go to [Google Accounts - Authorized Access to User Account](https://accounts.google.com/IssuedAuthSubTokens?hl=en), you can see a list of applications that have access to your Google account. You can revoke access for each individual one.